# Inserting data into newly created column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been successful in adding a new column to my table in MySQL. However I can't seem to add any data to it. I have tried using an `UPDATE` but I get an error.  I am including the original code for the table, and the `ALTER` that added the column and the attempted update.

```
CREATE TABLE `Teams` (
  `Team_id` INTEGER unsigned NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `team name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `league` CHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `div` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Team_id`)
);
```

the filling (abbreviated)

```
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`team name`,`league`,`div`) VALUES
('Free Agent','',''),
('Blue Jays','AL','East'),
('Yankees','AL','East'),
('Orioles','AL','East'),
...and so on
```

The `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE Teams
ADD City VARCHAR(20);
```

The `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Teams
SET City='NONE' where (team name='Free Agent');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape identifiers if they contain spaces:

```
UPDATE `Teams`
SET `City`='NONE' where (`team name`='Free Agent');
```

Comment: Shouldn't he always escape identifiers?

Comment: @wistar I'd prefer to go with the alternative approach - never use identifiers that require escaping